# Issue installing Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers

Tags: installation, java, eclipse, zip

I downloaded and it is a Zip file, but I can't extract and when I try to open it (on wich it is through Internet Explorer, that's the choice), nothing happens, i just have a bunch of windows opening for IE and I have to restart, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean when you say you are opening the file in Internet Explorer.

You need to find the .zip file from Windows Explorer or by using My Computer, then you can right-click the file and choose to unzip it. There will be an eclipse.exe along with the other Eclipse files in there.

Comment: Exactly I tried but I can't find anywhere, and the file I find is IE file, the icon is IE not zip or folder..... I don't know where the zip is

Comment: If you don't have the .zip file, then you never downloaded it. Go to www.eclipse.org and download it (again), and make sure you tell IE to 'Save' it and not 'Open' it.

Comment: I did it about 4 times... everytime I save it and do everything right ( like a regular download)

Comment: I still don't quite understand. Where are you telling Internet Explorer to save the file? Wherever you are saving the file, that's where the .zip will be. Also, it isn't 'like' a regular download; it is a regular download. Just find the file. If your IE won't let you download, you may have malware or a virus that is preventing you from downloading. I would also recommend using Firefox or Chrome to try the download.